# Android Studio 3.1 Instant Run not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-instant-run, instant-run

When I updated to Android Studio 3.1, Instant Run features (hot swap, warm swap) stopped working.
 
Every time when I click on Apply Changes (Instant Run Flash option), Android Studio is restarting my app (even for small UI changes) for every OS above lollipop. (On physical device as well as emulator)

My Instant Run Setting -

[image]

Message that I get from Android Studio - 
[image]

I tried -

1. Restarting laptop after Android Studio update.
2. Invalidating cache and restart
3. Closing the project and import it again

Nothing worked for me.
Please help me with this and kindly let me know any more information is needed from my side.

UPDATE:-

My Top level Gradle code -

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

In my `File > Project Structure > Project menu`, it is showing my `Gradle Version` as `4.4` and `Android Plugin Version` as `3.1.0`.

Comment: just disable it

Comment: @TimCastelijns Should I disable and re enable the Instant Run? or is there any issue with Instant Run so stop using it? I tried disabling and re enabling it, still the same issue.

Comment: there are many issues. Just disable it and don't think about it anymore

Comment: Hmm true even Vector assets not working :(

Answer (score -1):

If you are using old version version of gradle. Please upgrade to 4.x

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
```

Update the version and then try.

Comment: My current version after AS update is `3.1.0`, Should I downgrade it to `3.0.0` or upgrade to `4.1`?

Comment: upgrade to 4 then try. I faced the same and this worked in my case. You can also check.

Comment: Giving me error `Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0`

Comment: Add class path dependencies as  **classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1**

Comment: i am talking about gradle version not plugin version. Please refer this link: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html

Comment: @DäñishShärmà my Gradle Version is `4.4` and Android Plugin Version is `3.1.0`. I have seen it in `File > Project Structure > Project menu`.